# Is there a way to alter an incoming wiremock request urlPath programmatically?

Tags: wiremock

I'm currently hosting a wiremock server that can be hit remotely by both a native application and a web application. Unfortunately, due to constraints around where the server is hosted, the URL to reach the server is something like
`https://{baseURL}/wiremock`, which has the unintended consequence of prepending every request with `/wiremock`.

Is there any way to programmatically ignore the `/wiremock` portion of the request URL?

- I theoretically could replace the beginning of every request json to have `/wiremock`, but I'd prefer not to do that for continued ease of use and cross-team coordination.
- I've tried using a forwarding proxy.
- I've tried changing the binding address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll be able to do this very soon.

This commit (plus a couple of others) adds the ability to wrap, and therefore modify requests on the way in:
https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/commit/96f118ee96f07fb1ceab4da70269e02a5c4402d7

It's not in a released version yet, but I'm planning to push it in the next week or so, so look out for version 2.24.0.

Comment: Thanks @Tom! I saw that 2.24 was just released, but I'm not seeing a ton of documentation about how to implement a RequestFilter. Will this be coming soon?

Comment: Awesome. I was able to implement the filter + wrapper and the calls that have the extra `/wiremock` now have it removed.